# Current assets don't display in Add an Asset modal for matrix field; using {owner.slug} in path

Tags: assets, matrix

For two channels that restricts uploads to subdirectory/{owner.slug}, when I want to add an image in an existing entry, the Add an Asset modal window doesn't list the existing images (this is a matrix field that supports multiple images). All other cases where the restricted directory isn't a dynamic asset folder work fine. I've updated Asset Indexes and Cleared Caches, but still no luck. Any idea what's up? Thanks.

Comment: I thinks it's a bug and you should contact P&T directly with that. It'd be great if you could update here and tell us how things turned out ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of how Craft resolves dynamic paths (paths with {variables}) in them. For freshly created Matrix blocks haven't been saved yet and therefore don't have an {owner} yet.

If a dynamic path cannot be resolved, then Craft will point it to a temporary folder that is unique per user per field, but, as soon as you save the Entry and the Matrix block has an {owner}, it will resolve to where it should and all the Assets from the temporary folder that were selected will be move to the resolved folder.

Any Assets that have not been selected will remain in the temporary folder. This also holds true for unsaved Entries if you're using {slug}, for example.

Comment: Hi Andris, Seems odd to have the inconsistency in the modal window for the client, given that the entry is already saved, so the owner has been established. At any rate, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Well, while it seems inconsistent in modals, it's exactly consistent on a technical level :) We'll be addressing this in Craft 3.0, but it'll be a while until it's out..

Comment: Hmmm. Thw channel is to store businesses in a directory, and there is an Image matrix to allow the client to load a varied number of photos for each business. If the client adds the photos via the Assets tab (from the top nav bar) to that business's subdirectory, right now there is no way they can then view these photos from the business's entry as options to actually associate with that business via the modal. None of the current files are listed, even though they are already saved and associated with an existing entry. Sorry if I'm missing something, but that's pretty basic functionality.